# How to initiate next request before yielding in asynchronous generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pagination, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm attempting to get some data from a paginated API (specifically github's, but the API doesn't matter for this question). I'm using a python asynchronous generator to yield each individual row from each page. The code looks something like this:

```
async def get_data():
    cursor = None
    with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            async with session.get(build_url(cursor)):
                data = await response.json()

            yield from get_rows(data)

            if not has_next_page(data):
                return

            cursor = get_next_cursor(data)
```

So, this basically works. However, one of the minor flaws is that it doesn't initiate the next request until after all the rows have been yielded from the current page. Is there a good way to initiate that processing inside of this loop, before starting to yield? In particular, I want to make sure that the `async with` is still evaluated correctly when doing `asyncio.ensure_future`, which is the API for initiating background work.

Comment: Does `yield from` work in an `async def`?

Comment: As long as `get_rows` isn't async, yes.

Comment: Which Python version is that? In 3.6 I [get a syntax error](http://tpcg.io/1E3q0k): `SyntaxError: 'yield from' inside async function`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least one extra coroutine to achieve that, and bridge the two with an `asyncio.Queue`:

```
async def get_data():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def fetch_all_pages():
        cursor = None
        with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                async with session.get(build_url(cursor)):
                    data = await response.json()

                await queue.put(data)

                if not has_next_page(data):
                    # signal the peer to exit
                    await queue.put(None)
                    break

                cursor = get_next_cursor(data)

    asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_all_pages())

    while True:
        data = await queue.get()
        if not data:
            break
        yield from get_rows(data)
```

Comment: Has this code snipped been tested? You cannot use `yield from` in an asynchronous function.